# how to set background image which cover full with using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

I am trying to set my background image which should cover full width of screen .Currently it is only cover some % of full width. I used this css

```
.curve-img-container {
  background-image: url("../src/bg-curvy-desktop.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

it looks like this (**see in full screen mode) code sand box link**

[image]

but it should look like that

[image]

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cartwright-pw2mq?file=/src/styles.css:157-174

Comment: Is your height:200px or 200vh.  If its 200px then, image behaviour is correct.

Comment: i think you didn't get my point "see output in full screen mode"..from your point it is repeatint `y` direction

Comment: I cannot see the problem in the link you provided. Would you kindly also add your code to the post in addition to the external link? This is because external link can be nonaccessible in the future, while code in a snippet cannot.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cartwright-pw2mq?file=/src/styles.css:157-174

Comment: see it it is available

Comment: I've clicked on the link you sent on comment. Perhaps it's a problem with my browser, but I only see a dark background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with firefox

```
.curve-img-container {
background-image: url("../src/bg-curvy-desktop.svg");
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-repeat: round;
}
```

Comment: see in full screen mode ..!! it is repeating

Comment: just remove background size

Comment: yes it look like what I want but image is strech why ? due to small image ?

Comment: yes its problem about image size also you have set height . you can test with increase height

Comment: what is use of `background-repeat: round;`

Comment: The round option will repeat a tile horizontally and vertically without clipping, but the image may be resized